I'm using ag-grid with Vue installed through npm, how do I import the styles as of version 29.0.0?
I'm using ag-grid with Vue 2. I'm upgrading the version of ag-grid from 24 (ish) to 29.0.0. I have ag-grid installed with npm. With version 24 the project imported the styles sheets from the node modules.
According to their site: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/themes/ the path of the css has been updated and the old path is no longer available for version 29.0.0. It's changed from within a subfolder dist in the node modules to just being in a styles folder within the node package.
I don't see any styles folder in my @ag-grid-community folder. And I can't find any .css files in there to link to when I just do a search within the @ag-grid-community node package.
Is there some way that I should be generating these files? Should I be importing the CSS in a different way as of version 29.0.0?

In my package.json file I only had these two lines of code:
    "@ag-grid-community/core": "^29.2.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/vue": "^29.2.0",

I needed to add a third line to the dependencies for importing the styles module. It's a separate import in the version 29.0.0.
"@ag-grid-community/styles": "^29.2.0",
Then I can import the styles as suggested in the docs:
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css'


Sorry for the late reply.
But following the documentation and also the migration tutorial, you're doing it right.
Could you describe your context better?
I've made a CodeSandbox to show how the v29+ css path update works.
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ag-grid-vue
      style="width: 500px; height: 500px"
      class="ag-theme-quartz"
      :columnDefs="columnDefs"
      :rowData="rowData"
    >
    </ag-grid-vue>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { AgGridVue } from "@ag-grid-community/vue";
import { ModuleRegistry } from "@ag-grid-community/core";
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model";
import "@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"; // Imported style just like the documentation says
import "@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css"; // Imported style just like the documentation says
ModuleRegistry.registerModules([ClientSideRowModelModule]);
</script>

Here are the installed dependencies (after v29, they follow the same import pattern), so although I used version 31.x.x, it also applies to versions after v29:
 "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/vue": "31.3.2",
    "@ag-grid-community/core": "31.3.2",
    "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "31.3.2",
    "@ag-grid-community/styles": "31.3.2"
  },


Thanks for answering! I posted what turned out to be the answer. That I needed to import styles as a separate npm package. I was switching between version 24 to 29. And using server-side processing for the data.
